# How to testing match escape characters in string?

Tags: javascript, regex

How to testing match escape characters in string?

What to need:

`/^\888$/g.test('\888')`

\888 = true

888 = false

```js
console.log(/^888$/g.test('888'));

console.log(/^888$/g.test('\888'));
```

Comment: Um why not just "888" === "888" ?

Comment: `console.log('888' === '\888')` => `true`.

Comment: "888" === "\888" must be = false.  "888" === "888" must be = true

Comment: Where do you get that `\888` from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The backslash `\` is reserved for use as an **escape** character in JavaScript.To use a backslash literally on your regex or any where for string operation, you need to use two backslashes e.g `\\`

That's why `console.log('888' === '\888')` returns true because '\8\8\8' is actually '888'

```js
console.log('888' === '\888')
console.log('\888' === '\8\88')
```

Answer (score 1):

You are escaping the first `8`, you need to escape the `\`.

```js
console.log(/^888$/g.test('888'));

console.log(/^888$/g.test('\\888'));
```

Comment: Thank you, but no. It is "\\" -  how new symbol "\".